# How to write an approximation equation in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, statistics, r-markdown

[image]

*Like in the image above, I have tried the latex version of `\approx` and have tried escaping it with `\\approx` but still not luck. Just need the code chunk to create the approximation equation symbol for Rmarkdown, Thank you in advance.*

**Found my answer, the code is below**

```
 ---
 title: "approx"
 author: "Daniel"
 date: "6/4/2020"
 output: html_document
 ---

 y $\approx$ x
```

Comment: it worked okay for me -- im assuming you are outputting to pdf? It did seem to baulk if there was a space after the dollar; `$y \approx x$` rendered, but `$ y \approx x$` errorred

Comment: you can use `x = 2; y = 3; txt = paste0("$", x, "\\approx", y, "$")` in the code chnk and then call inline using `<backtick>r txt<bactick>` . If this isn't what you're after can you edit your question with a small example please.

Comment: I did figure out that using the \approx between two $ was the trick, ex: `$\approx$`

Comment: Please consider writing up an answer Daniel which shows your code -- it might help future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode works inside code chunks

```
plot(1:10,runif(10), main = "y \U2248 x")
```

Comment: you can also use `plotmath` in a plot i.e. `plot(1:10,runif(10), main = ~y %~~% x)`